# rsync / robocopy /MIR to azure

Tags: azure, robocopy

We are looking to do two things with azure for off site backup:

1) We need to mirror local dir struct up to azure, like robocopy /MIR command

2) We need to purge files older than ____ days from azure storage.

What is the direct path to this place?

Comment: @LMFAO_A_JOKE robocopy can copy to azure?

Comment: I may have missed that part. I was thinking `\\server\share` but see if this helps any [Azure Storage Backup](http://serverfault.com/questions/544558/using-windows-azure-storage-for-backup). You have NO UNC `\\server\share` I assume, correct? Here's the [Azure Backup - Microsoft](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/backup/)

Comment: Okay a couple more things to provide but it appears the `AzCopy` is the `Robocopy` equivalent for Azure and there are also PowerShell command CmdLets too [Article 1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2014/05/12/introducing-microsoft-azure-file-service.aspx) and here's [Article 2](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2012/12/03/azcopy-uploading-downloading-files-for-windows-azure-blobs.aspx). . . I would test these routes myself probably but I'm not using Azure and I appologize for not seeing that initially in your question. Maybe those will help you get started

Comment: So 10 hours later, the below answer is basically the exact same thing I recommended initially if you have `\\server\share` setup. Here's a TechNet blog that talks about setting up an [Azure File Share](http://blogs.technet.com/b/canitpro/archive/2014/09/23/step-by-step-create-a-file-share-in-azure.aspx) as well. If this is the case, use Robocopy for that part and forfiles for the recursive cleanup of all files older than X number of days. You'd use forfiles with a mapped drive or pushd though and not UNC path.

Comment: Vote for this feature: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217298-storage/suggestions/6930594-azcopy-should-support-mir-option-like-robocopy

Answer (score 2):

There is an official Microsoft "Robocopy like command line tool" to copy data from/to Azure Blobs, it's called Azcopy, latest version is available here : http://aka.ms/downloadazcopy

Unfortunately, Azure Blob Storage doesn't allow the creation of a dir structure (there is only one level available called Container) so it's not a good solution for you.

So In your case, I would rather recommend to use Azure File (An SMB 3.0 File Service) and connect a Windows machine (8 and later, 2012 and later) to it. Network Trafic will be encrypted (one of coolest new features of SMB 3.0 : SMB Encryption), Authentication is done using Azure Storage Account name & key.

Few steps to configure :

1. create a Azure Storage Account
2. Create an Azure File Share in this Azure Storage Account
3. On a Windows Server (2012 or later) or Windows Client (8 or later), mount the Azure File Share as a network drive
4. Use robocopy to copy your data

More information : How to use Azure File
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-files/

Comment: How to mount the Azure File Share from a remote Windows machine? In Azure, when I click on the "connect" icon of my file share, it reads: "To connect to this file share, run this command from any Windows virtual machine on the same subscription and location" - but my Windows machine is not in the same location.
When I run the `net use`, I am getting: `System error 67: The network name cannot not be found."` I wonder if there is a way to enable WebDAV in order to map the file share as a network drive.

Comment: Hi, this is not Webdav but SMB 3.0 so you need to open TCP 445 on the FW/router where is connected your remote Windows Machine (This one must be at least Windows Server 2012 or Windows 8 to support SMB 3). I don't think that Azure File provides Webdav access

Comment: Thanks, understood. Problem is that I might not necessarily be in control of the firewalls where the remote windows machine is. (i.e. delivering a windows desktop client software to customers that needs to access Azure). So I guess WebDAV would be a workaround. Yes, it's not supported out of the box by Azure, but it's a standard protocol that could be enabled in IIS. So, using IIS and configuring the IIS documents  root folder to be the Azure file share might work. At least that's my theory.

Answer (score 2):

It would also be possible to do with by replicating your storage with the use of an software defined storage solution over iSCSI.